# A short form for «as (it-) is»?

Tags: abbreviations

May there be an acronym, an abbreviation for the term *«as is»*, *«as it is»*? The context the term used: to leave *as it is*, remain unchanged.

P.S.: Found a word *stet*, which translates to *let it stand*.

Comment: FWIW, there is the fixed latinism [_sic_](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sic)  (thus, this way, that way) used in writing after quoting something literally, especially to justify what you consider wrong or outdated orthography or grammar. It comes from _sic erat scriptum_, which could be (a bit freely) translated as 'this is how it was written'

Comment: I think you should write *stet* into its own answer, since I think it's a better option than any of the others (including the one you've accepted).

Comment: Some more context (like an example) would definitely help here.

Comment: @chzzh Could you write an example of code annotation then? With the literal code and the comment you'd like to add to it. Make one up with a "hello world" if you haven't any real code at the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have found for yourself, a very suitable choice would be *[stet](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stet#English)*. This is a subjunctive 'let it stand' or 'it should stand'.

In the comments it was clarified that the intended use here is code annotations, which makes *stet* even more appropriate since it has a history of being used as annotation while editing a document. Typically the proofreader/editor might indicate a change they thought was suitable, but if the author disagreed with the change they would write *stet* indicating that the original should remain without the changes.

Comment: Curious, did you intend to make this community wiki?

Comment: @cmw It felt appropriate since it was the OP's answer, taken from where they edited into the question.

Comment: It's up to you, but although the suggestion is OP's, the explanation is yours and so you deserve just as much credit. I can reverse the wiki-ization if you'd like, but as I said, up to you.

Comment: @cmw Happy for you to reverse the CW-ization, thank you for offering. :)

Answer (score 6):

You could consider *in statu quo ante*, "in the state in which it was before".

Comment: Not the biggest fan of doing so, but this could potentially be made into a proper acronym: ISQA.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're asking on this particular stack, I imagine you're looking for specifically a *Latin* phrase that can be used or abbreviated in English.

With those criteria, the best I can think of is *in situ*, literally "in place" but generally meaning something more like "unmodified" or "undisturbed".

Comment: I'm struggling to imagine a context where this expression would be appropriate - even in English beauracratese the expression means "left where found", eg. in archeology or criminalistics. This it's a description of fact, "found this way" or "is currently in its proper place". I'm positive it can't be used to mean "don't modify" (situs is a description of location, not of quality) or as a command or suggestion, as can't noun phrases in Latin in general - you need a verb.

Comment: @Unbrutal_Russian Not as a command on its own, but I'm sure I've seen instructions like "leave in situ".

Comment: @Draconis Sure, that would be possible, but the meaning of that is "don't move around" while the OP is looking for a note meaning "don't modify the contents". This requires a different verb entirely, *mūtāre,* or more preferrably something like *nē tangās,* or *sīc voluī/sīc estō* (the latter in fact already in use in the European tradition shortened as *sic*, which it only now occurs to me probably started out as a note to correctors).